# How to capture the result of a regex-powered command in Vim normal mode?

Tags: vim, gvim, regex, script, word-count

I want to find the number of times 'x' is present in my file, so I submit `%s/x//gn` and get the correct answer.

How can I capture the resultant count into a variable using vimscript on the command-line?

The following solution was hinted at by an answer below:

```
:let cnt=0
:g/x/let cnt=cnt+1
:echo cnt
```

However, `cnt` is made to store the total number of lines in the buffer that have an `x`, not how many `x`s there are in the whole file.

So, the original question still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does the trick:

```
:echo eval(join(map(range(1, line('$')), 'len(substitute(getline(v:val),"[^x]","","g"))')," + "))
```

This replaces all non-`x` characters with nothing, counts the number of remaining characters (should be `x`s), and adds up this result for each line in the file.

I got the idea for this technique using the `map` function from [Dennis Williamson](https://superuser.com/questions/255368/how-to-find-the-line-with-the-maximum-number-of-columns-characters-in-vim-gvim/255438#255438), in another post on Vim scripting.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered by the Vim FAQ ["How do I count the number of times a particular word occurs in a buffer?"](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vimfaq.html#11.10)

Comment: The link you have mentions the command [:g](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g), which can be used to count **lines** where a regex matches, but not the number of times it matches on a line, which is what I need.

Comment: @drapkin11: Good point.  I know it could be done with a Vim script, but I'm not aware of a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
:let cnt=0
:g/^.*may/let cnt=cnt+1
:echo cnt
```

So you will then see how many lines have the word 'may' in them at least once. So the following text will be counted as 1:

```
Your mileage may vary. You may have already won.
```

Easy.

Comment: thanks, but this is too similar to @Heptite's suggestion, which does not resolve my original question. Note that I need to have a count of *all* instances of a match on each line - not just one.